# How to clear cached memory in Debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, cache

If I run a `free -m`, I get this output:

[image: Free -m output]

Is there a command that I could use to clear the used memory? I have tried this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

It will ask for `sudo`. But even after `sudo`, it gives bad command error.

Here is the link where I got to know about [drop_caches](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_drop_caches.html).

I am just looking for a way on how to clear the cache.

Comment: Off topic. Belongs to superuser. Voting to close.

Comment: Why are you asking?? It is usually not worth the effort!

Comment: I want to test the performance of an application , which initiates several processes , and generate some statistics , If i run the same application for two times the statistics will not be accurate , and also clear understanding of how the application behaves in each of scenarios  , will remain as a mystery . If cache is the matter for its performance , I definitely need to know if there is any way there  to clear the cache  so that I can take care of it . I am really sorry , If this stack overflow is not a platform to ask such system level questions .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this as `root` (not sudo):

```
#sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

is that the redirect happens in the initial shell - i.e. under your own account - before the "sudo echo 1" happens, which isn't the part that really needs root access.  You need to get the opening of drop_caches by ">" to be inside of the sudo.  One lazy way (lazy because it clones the 3 back to stdout, which you don't actually need) is:

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

The options to write into drop_caches are:

1. Free pagecache
2. Free dentries and inodes
3. Free pagecache, dentries, and inodes.

And you *should* sync first, so all in all:

```
sync ; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

or if you don't like the spurious "3" on stdout:

```
sudo sh -c 'sync ; echo 3 >/prod/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make it automatically using `crontab` as `root`.

```
~$ sudo crontab -e
```

You'll see the your/new crontab file like it:

```
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

And you'll add this one in new lines to flush every hour:

```
# Every hour flushes the memory cache on system
0 * * * * sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

I see in my `syslog` tailf output.

```
~$ tailf /var/log/syslog | grep 'cron'
```

And I see the output below:

```
May 31 14:07:16 debian crontab[17353]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
May 31 14:07:20 debian crontab[17353]: (root) END EDIT (root)

...

May 31 15:00:02 debian CRON[22169]: (root) CMD (sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches)
May 31 15:17:01 debian CRON[18828]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```